# How to select records between two dates using only month and year in PHP and MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

So I have this code:

```
$date_from = "2017-04-01";
$date_to = "2017-05-01"

$stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM records where created_at BETWEEN :start_date AND :end_date");

$stmt->execute([':start_date' => $date_from, ':end_date' => $date_to]);
```

My `created_at` is a `timestamp` field.

My problem here is that though it works, I only need to select between months and year only in the `created_at` field because in my code, the date is also included in selecting data. I only want `"2017-04" - "2017-5"` records for example so that even if a record like `"2017-05-31"` is still under `"2017-5"`. What am I missing here?

Let's say I have a record where the `created_at` value is `"2017-05-01"`. It will not be selected because it's not between the given dates that's why I need to fix my code to only use months and years even if the dates given are with date.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You need to use Like in condition. like `where created_at like '$date_from%'`

Comment: Next time, you can edit the question instead of removing and creating a new version.

Comment: So you want 31st May to be included?

Comment: @marekful yes sorry, I panicked

Comment: @Strawberry yes as long as it is under that month

Comment: You can use the LAST_DAY function

Comment: Does the problem solved? If not, you mean you want to get 2017-04-firstday until 2017-05-lastday records? Not clearly understand your request...

Answer (score 2):

format your datetime.

You can use a string comparison.

`DATE_FORMAT('2017-04-01','%Y%m')` return date: `201704`.

so your where clause should be

`"created_at DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%Y%m') >=` `DATE_FORMAT($date_from,'%Y%m') and DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%Y%m') <= DATE_FORMAT($date_to,'%Y%m')` "

Comment: I tried it and even if I have the same months like from is 5 and to is 5, I also get the next month records.

Comment: i dont know how your table designed. maybe you can change logic operators?

Answer (score 1):

Convert your Dates to timestamp in php or even mysql

```
PHP:
$date_from_timestamp = strtotime($date_from);
$date_from_timestamp = strtotime($date_to);


MySQL:
UNIX_TIMESTAMP($date_from)
UNIX_TIMESTAMP($date_to)
```

Comment: please try to read my post again sir, thank you for the help though

Comment: What is the content of the timestamp field? 2017-08-15 09:05:12 or 1502780645

Answer (score 0):

```
$date_from = "2017-04-01";
$date_to = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($date_from." +1 months"));

$stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM records where created_at BETWEEN :start_date AND :end_date");

$stmt->execute([':start_date' => strtotime($date_from), ':end_date' => strtotime($date_to]));
```

Try this. If you created_at is timestamp. Your searching criteria also need to be timestamp

To search within a month or year u may do like following.

```
 $date_from = "2017-04-01";
 $date_to = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($date_from." +1 months")); // to add one month from 2017-05-01
```

Comment: Yes this works but I need to search between months and years only as you can see in my code I also have date

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are ignoring the day of the input and requested to get both April and May records

```
$date_from = "2017-04-01";
$date_to = "2017-05-01";

$stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM records where created_at BETWEEN :start_date AND :end_date");

$stmt->execute([
    ':start_date' => date("Y-m-01 00:00:00",strtotime($date_from)), 
    ':end_date' => date("Y-m-31 23:59:59",strtotime($date_to))
]);
```